# Indexed collection of sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Prove or disprove

> Let $\{U_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ be an indexed collection of sets. If $\Lambda$ is countable, then the union of $\{U_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ is countable.

Comment: Are there any other restrictions on U?

Comment: U does not have any restrictions

Answer (score 2):

I think a trivial answer is this:

No, because if even one of $U_\alpha$ is uncountable, then the collection cannot be countable.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\{\mathbb{R}\}$.

The set is countable (finite sets are countable), yet its union, namely $\mathbb{R}$, is not.